# Why is 'just' the supremum used for both 2-sample kolmogorov-smirnov test, as well as the kuiper's test, rather than a more comprehensive difference?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am looking for a method to compare two distributions of numbers (whether they differ in underlying distribution).

However, after reading thhrough respective wikipedia pages ( [kuipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_test) , [2-sample KS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) ) I am unsure why both tests make use of the **supremum** in distance on the cumulative probability axis rather than a difference metric which used the full distributions of both samples, like for example the full **area** of difference between the two distributions. It seems to me that this would be a more informative metric, as less of the distributions' information is discarded.

Is this an existing concept I am unaware of, or is there a specific reason why this is not desired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the original reason is mathematical tractability. The distribution of the supremum is the same for any continuous null hypothesis distribution, and there's a reasonably well-behaved infinite series for it, and it was worked out a long time ago.

Other summaries do exist: the [Cramér-von Mises/Anderson](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-33/issue-3/On-the-Distribution-of-the-Two-Sample-Cramer-von-Mises/10.1214/aoms/1177704477.full) test uses the integral of the squared difference, and the [weighted Kaplan-Meier](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531492) tests of Pepe & Fleming use weighted areas between CDFs. The K-S test just got in first.